# How can I initialize a std::chrono::duration constant without using namespace chrono?

Tags: c++, literals, c++20, c++-chrono

I want to use this code

```
static constexpr auto set_time = 1s;
```

But I don't want to use `using namespace chrono;`

Error C3688 invalid literal suffix "s"; could not find the literal operator or pattern of the literal operator " operator ""s"

Comment: q.v. [chrono_literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/symbol_index/chrono_literals)

Comment: I think the title should be "How to initialize std::chrono::duration constant without chrono_literals"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

Comment: `static constexpr auto set_time = std::chrono::1s;`
I need something like this but it doesn't work

Comment: namespace `chrono` doesn't contain a thing named `1s`

Comment: @zerotort But why? UDL names without a leading underscore are reserved for the standard library, so this `s` will never conflict with anything from other namespaces. And `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` will only imports the UDLs, ignoring the rest of `std::chrono`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat maybe it's in a header and they follow the coding guideline of not wanting to place using-declarations in headers?  (Although if that's true it should probably be `inline`)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if there is no conflict, then this is good, I think it will work too

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds(1)` this option of course I like more because it writes clearly that it is seconds and not just 1 character s

Answer (score 6):

That line is exactly equivalent to:

```
static constexpr auto set_time = std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s(1);
```

Comment: Just `std::chrono::seconds(1)`

Comment: @StaceyGirl more than one way to skin a cat :)  I think your method would only work for whole numbers whereas mine could work for `1.5s` for example, and extensible to other chrono literals